# Asynchronous data in secure storage cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous, storage

I have this piece of code:

```
let config = {};
    var ss;
        var _init = async function() {
          ss = await new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage(
            function() {
              console.log("OK");
            },
            function() {
              navigator.notification.alert(
                "Por favor configure um pin para desbloquear o telemóvel. A aplicação não consegue funcionar sem isso.",
                function() {
                  ss.secureDevice(
                    function() {
                      _init();
                    },
                    function() {
                      _init();
                    }
                  );
                },
                "Screen lock is disabled"
              );
            },
            "Stocks2018"
          );
    
      await ss.set(
          function(key) {
            console.log("Set " + key);
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log("Error " + error);
          },
          "config",
          JSON.stringify(config)
        );

        check_btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
            // Store configurations in local storage
            config = {
                web_service_url: web_service_url.value,
                serie: serie.value,
                num_col_menu: num_col_menu.value,
                opcao_login: opcao_login.value,
                controlo_ecra: controlo_ecra.value,
                teclado: teclado.value,
                peso: peso.value,
                posicao_inicial_ean_13: posicao_inicial_ean_13.value,
                num_digitos_ean_13: num_digitos_ean_13.value,
                tamanho_total_gs1_128_sem_qt: tamanho_total_gs1_128_sem_qt.value,
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt: posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt.value,
                num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt: num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt.value,
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote: posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote.value,
                num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote: num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote.value,
                tamanho_total_gs1_128_com_qt: tamanho_total_gs1_128_com_qt.value,
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_ref: posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_ref.value,
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_ref: num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_ref.value,
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_qt: posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_qt.value,
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_qt: num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_qt.value,
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_lote: posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_lote.value,
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_lote: num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_lote.value
            };

            let global = {
                fornecedor: "",
                documento: "",
                numero: "",
                data_validacao: "",
                prdcd: [],
                prdds: [],
                doccabid: [],
                doccabnum: [],
                doccabdt: [],
                doclinprtcd: [],
                doclinqtd: [],
                doclinlote: []
            }

            let produtos = [];

            await ss.set(
              function(key) {
                console.log("Set " + key);
              },
              function(error) {
                console.log("Error " + error);
              },
              "config",
              JSON.stringify(config)
            );

            await ss.set(
              function(key) {
                console.log("Set " + key);
              },
              function(error) {
                console.log("Error " + error);
              },
              "global",
              JSON.stringify(global)
            );

            await ss.set(
              function(key) {
                console.log("Set " + key);
              },
              function(error) {
                console.log("Error " + error);
              },
              "produtos",
              JSON.stringify(produtos)
            );

            navigator.notification.alert("Configurações aplicadas com sucesso!", () => {}, "Sucesso");
        });

        updateInputsInConfig();

        async function updateInputsInConfig(){
            var config;
            await ss.get(
               function(value) {
                 console.log("Get " + value);
                 config = value;
               },
               function(error) {
                 console.log("Error " + error);
               },
               "config"
            );

            if(config !== "{}"){
                console.log("Dentro do config");
                var parsed_config = JSON.parse(config);
                web_service_url.value = parsed_config.web_service_url;
                serie.value = parsed_config.serie;
                num_col_menu.value = parsed_config.num_col_menu;
                opcao_login.value = parsed_config.opcao_login;
                controlo_ecra.value = parsed_config.controlo_ecra;
                teclado.value = parsed_config.teclado;
                peso.value = parsed_config.peso;
                posicao_inicial_ean_13.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_ean_13;
                num_digitos_ean_13.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_ean_13;
                tamanho_total_gs1_128_sem_qt.value = parsed_config.tamanho_total_gs1_128_sem_qt;
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt;
                num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt;
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote;
                num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_gs1_128_sem_qt_lote;
                tamanho_total_gs1_128_com_qt.value = parsed_config.tamanho_total_gs1_128_com_qt;
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_ref.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_ref;
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_ref.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_ref;
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_qt.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_qt;
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_qt.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_qt;
                posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_lote.value = parsed_config.posicao_inicial_gs1_128_com_qt_lote;
                num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_lote.value = parsed_config.num_digitos_gs1_128_com_qt_lote;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that my get and set functions of secure storage happen after the updateInputsInConfig function. I want them to happen before. Why is this happening and how can I solve it? Also does data in secure storage stay stored even after the app has closed?
I also get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at updateInputsInConfig
```

What is this about? How can I solve it?

How can I make the updateInputsInConfig function execute after the gets and set of secure storage?

Comment: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` usually means trying to parse `undefined`

Comment: do all these `ss.get` `ss.set` return Promises? I'd be surprised if `new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage` returned a Promise!

Comment: Looking at the documentation, `await` is **never** mentioned or used in [cordova -plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage#readme) - perhaps you don't understand `async`/`await`?

Comment: I don't know if it returns a Promise. i suppose so because I did console.log to see what comes first, and the last function came first

Comment: well, the documentation makes no mention of promises, and since there's callbacks to those `.set` and `.get` calls, I doubt Promises are being returned at all - I think you've assumed `async`/`await` works with asynchronous code in general, a common misconception, it does not. It's purely syntactic "sugar" for Promises - also, you'd NEVER `await new` anything - except maybe `new Promise` - since only `new Promise` returns a `Promise` that you *can* `await`

Comment: So how can I make it synchronous?

Comment: you can't - you just have to follow the instructions in the documentation

Comment: The docs don't say much https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-secure-storage-echo

Comment: they don't mention Promises - it's all callbacks

Comment: to be honest, not sure why you are calling `ss.secureDevice` in the `new cordova.plugins.SecureStorage` error handler

Comment: Why you say I shouldn't call ss.secureDevice?

Comment: no, ignore that last comment

Comment: I think, besides the misuse of async/await, another issue is that first `await ss.set(....., "config", JSON.stringify(config));` - `config` here is **undefined**

Comment: but I declare it with {} before setting up the secure storage like this: ```let config = {};```

Comment: well, not in the code you've posted